# Get a sparse matrix of quantum circuit

Tags: programming, qiskit, matrix-representation

Is there a way that can obtain sparse matrix of quantum circuit? I used to check my quantum circuit with `quantum_info.Operator`, but for large number of qubits, it is difficult because of the memory allocation limit. Is it available in qiskit? or should I build elementary gates in sparse matrix format? Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by irrelevant?

Comment: Sorry, I misused the word. I mean the quantum circuit cannot be converted to matrix because of the large size of matrix.

Comment: As an extreme example consider $H^{\otimes n}$.

Answer (score 1):

There are classes for Operators, States, Channels, Measures, Randomness, Analysis and Synthesis in Quantum Information ( qiskit.quantum_info ).

There is a specific class called SparsePauliOp. It is constructed as a Sparse N-qubit operator in a Pauli basis representation. It seems to be using SciPy internally for creating the sparse matrix. It can be used for performing operator arithmetic for hundred of qubits if the number of non-zero Pauli basis terms is sufficiently small. Please find further details [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.SparsePauliOp.html#qiskit.quantum_info.SparsePauliOp) in the Qiskit Terra API specifications. Qiskit Aqua as has a class called Matrix Operator where we can pass a Sparse Matrix. Please find further details here in the [Qiskit Aqua API specifications](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.aqua.operators.legacy.MatrixOperator.html).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Then 2-qubit gates (ex. CNOT) can be built by the classes that you recommended?

Comment: You could use qiskit.quantum_info.two_qubit_cnot_decompose. Please find the details here - https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.two_qubit_cnot_decompose.html